# Issues with activator-akka-spray template

Tags: java, akka, spray, typesafe

Hi I'm trying the typesafe's activator-akka-spray, but unfortunately cannot see what happens when I run it, it gives me several messages like that:

```
[info] Running Rest
[INFO] [05/25/2015 15:23:40.635] [akka-spray-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [a
kka://akka-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to /0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] [05/25/2015 15:23:40.635] [akka-spray-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [a
kka://akka-spray/deadLetters] Message [akka.io.Tcp$Bound] from Actor[akka://akka
-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0#-1030525738] to Actor[akka://akka-spray/deadLette
rs] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned
off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.lo
g-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [05/25/2015 15:24:58.034] [akka-spray-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [a
kka://akka-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/0] Message [akka.dispatch.sysmsg.DeathW
atchNotification] from Actor[akka://akka-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/0#7548014
77] to Actor[akka://akka-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/0#754801477] was not deli
vered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted
with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-d
uring-shutdown'.
[INFO] [05/25/2015 15:27:57.538] [akka-spray-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [a
kka://akka-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/1] Message [akka.actor.Terminated] from
 Actor[akka://akka-spray/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2#-1399322655] to Actor[akka
://akka-spray/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/1#-183927807] was not delivered. [3] dead
letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configurati
on settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Platform:
Win 7 64 bits
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

activator version: typesafe-activator-1.2.10-minimal

Build.sbt

```
   name := """activator-akka-spray"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

resolvers += "spray nightlies" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-actor"       % "2.2.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-slf4j"       % "2.2.0",
  "ch.qos.logback"      % "logback-classic"  % "1.0.13",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-can"        % "1.2-20130712",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-routing"    % "1.2-20130712",
  "io.spray"           %% "spray-json"       % "1.2.3",
  "org.specs2"         %% "specs2"           % "1.14"         % "test",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-testkit"    % "1.2-20130712" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-testkit"     % "2.2.0"        % "test",
  "com.novocode"        % "junit-interface"  % "0.7"          % "test->default"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-language:_",
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8"
)

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

Besides, that I cannot realize how to open the webpage for sending those requests to Spray, tried find any documentation inside github relevant to this but really couldn't find it.

Regards